# phpfox v4 blank page after installing language pack

Tags: phpfox

I have a question about installing a language pack on phpfox v4. After installing it, i get a blank page and the installation of the language pack is incomplete. I try to enable debug mode, but it shows `Missing "phpfox.json" file.`.

Version is 4.3.0 built 5, turkish language pack, the procedure is automated in the backend, only to click install button in admin cp, the server OS is Linux, Ubuntu 14

Comment: I don't know PhpFox and can't help you, but you are not giving many details. What version of PhpFox is it? What language pack are you talking about? What's the procedure you followed to install it? What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi Bjarki, Version 4.3.0 built 5, turkish language pack, the procedure is automated in the backend, only to click install button in admin cp, the server OS is Linux, Ubuntu 14

Comment: Ok, please [edit] your question and add these details there. Not everybody reads the comments.